# A word similar to lofty

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

I'm looking for an adjective that means lofty, intangible, hard to incorporate into every day life,  not down-to-earth. It would describe an idea or concept.

ETA: Example of sentence I would use it in:

> It's hard to feel strong emotions about something that is so *_*_

Comment: Could you give us a sentence that shows the context you're using it in?

Comment: **Abstract** or **hypothetical** would actually capture the meaning better, I think.

Comment: Something about your avatar - "dmr 165" - weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't say these are all the same, so here are some possibilities...

lofty -> noble

intangible -> ethereal, abstract, virtual

hard to incorporate into every day life -> intricate, complex

not down-to-earth -> out there, far out, bizarre, unusual, extraordinary

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few suggestions:

Elevated, grandiose, exalted, high-minded...

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion ([Synonyms](http://thesaurus.com/browse/lofty)):

aerial, airy, high-rise, lifted, [raised, sky-high, skyscraping, skyward, soaring, spiring, tall, towering]

Hope this helps